# pgpool構築でprimaryサーバーが消えて、DB操作ができません。

Tags: sql, postgresql, database

2台のPostgresDBサーバーでpgpool（ストリーミングレプリケーション）構築中に下記記載の現象が起こりました。
解決方がお分かりの方は教えてほしいです。
構築は、[こちらの公式ページ](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/ja/html/example-cluster.html)を参考にして行いました。

## 不具合内容

下記で分かるように用意した2台のサーバーの**pg_role**がいずれも**standby**になっています。
どちらかが**primary**になっていなければならないはずです。
これはバグでしょうか。
何か解決策があれば教えてください。

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -p 9999 -U pgpool postgres -c "show pool_nodes"
 node_id |   hostname    | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last
_status_change
---------+---------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----
----------------
 0       | 172.24.194.64 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2022
-08-02 22:36:54
 1       | 172.24.194.65 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2022
-08-02 22:36:54
```

## 試したこと

- `pcp_promote_node -U pgpool -n 0`でroleをprimaryには昇格させられたが、pg_roleは変わらない。

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -p 9999 -U pgpool postgres -c "show pool_nodes"
 node_id |   hostname    | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | re
plication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change  
---------+---------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---
----------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | 172.24.194.64 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | standby | 0          | true              | 0                 |   
                |                        | 2022-08-02 13:43:13
 1       | 172.24.194.65 | 5432 | down   | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 |   
                |                        | 2022-08-02 13:43:13
(2 行)
```

- サービス再起動・サーバーの再起動などを試したが失敗

## その他情報

- pcp_dog_info

```
-bash-4.2$ pcp_watchdog_info -p 9898 -U pgpool
Password:
2 2 YES server1:9999 Linux mbl-db-01 172.24.194.64

172.24.194.64 :9999 Linux mbl-db-01 172.24.194.64 9999 9000 4 LEADER 0 MEMBER
172.24.194.65 :9999 Linux mbl-db-02 172.24.194.65 9999 9000 7 STANDBY 0 MEMBER
```

- pcp_node_info

```
pcp_node_info --verbose -p 9898 -U pgpool -n 0
Password:
Hostname               : 172.24.194.64 
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Backend Status Name    : up
Role                   : standby
Backend Role           : standby
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : none
Replication Sync State : none
Last Status Change     : 2022-08-02 22:36:54
-bash-4.2$ pcp_node_info --verbose -p 9898 -U pgpool -n 1
Password:
Hostname               : 172.24.194.65
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Backend Status Name    : up
Role                   : standby
Backend Role           : standby
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : none
Replication Sync State : none
Last Status Change     : 2022-08-02 22:36:54
```

- ログでprimaryノードが見つけられていないのがわかる

```
#  sudo less /var/log/pgpool_log/pgpool-2022-08-03_104124.log
-略-
2022-08-03 11:45:12.404: sr_check_worker pid 2559: DEBUG:  verify_backend_node_status: there's no primary node
2022-08-03 11:45:12.404: sr_check_worker pid 2559: DEBUG:  node status[0]: 2
2022-08-03 11:45:12.404: sr_check_worker pid 2559: DEBUG:  node status[1]: 2
-略-
```

## 環境

- サーバーOS:CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
- postgreSQL:psql (PostgreSQL) 14.4
- pgpool:4.3.2 (tamahomeboshi)